# How to export grouped .txt list to .csv in column format

Tags: excel, bash, csv, format, export-to-excel

I have a grouped list in a .txt file that I am trying to convert into a .csv file that I can export to Excel in the following format using bash. Does anyone know how to do this?

Original:

> Name: aaaa
>
> Owner: aaa
>
> Oncall: aa
>
> --
>
> Name: bbbb
>
> Owner: bbb
>
> Oncall: bb
>
> --
>
> Name: cccc
>
> Owner: ccc
>
> Oncall: cc

Desired format:

> Name, Owner, Oncall
>
> aaaa, aaa, aa
>
> bbbb, bbb, bb,
>
> cccc, ccc, cc

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried simply doing a search for `<carriage return><header term>` and replacing it with a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Transposing rows and columns: 3 methods'

http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/transposing-rows-and-columns-3-methods

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v RS='--' \
'!header++{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2)
     printf "%s%s",substr($i,1,length($i)-1),(i==NF-1?"\n":",")
 }{
   for(i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2)
     printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?"\n":",")
 }' file
```

The record separtor is set to `--` in order to catch the 3 `key: value` at once.

The first  block statement prints the header only once.

The second block statement loops over found values and prints them with comma as delimiter.